# Is there a testing site available where we can test our OAuth 1.0a signatures?

Tags: testing, oauth

Ideally, it would be a site where it provides you with the keys, tokens, and secrets, then tells you what it was expecting for your signature based on the info you sent.  I'm trying to build an OAuth library with some testable controls for specific circumstances and I have no idea if it's doing like it should... maybe something like jsfiddle, but for OAuth?  Anything like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the LinkedIn OAuth Test Console at http://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console.